# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS stopped detecting only my internet

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet

Hello and thanks in advance for any help.

Last night Ubuntu asked me to update, which I allowed. 
This morning, I woke up and turned on my computer, and it didn't allow me to connect to the internet. I checked the networks detected and it showed a bunch of them, but not mine. All the other computers and phones connect normally to the internet, through wireless and through cable. Only the laptop with Ubuntu stopped recognizing only my internet, which I had already configured. It also came to my attention that a power outage had occured during this night, so I'm not sure if the update broke it or not.
Yet again, thanks in advance :)

Edit: My laptop is a Acer Aspire 5820TG, which used to be able to connect to the internet until today. I can connect to the internet through wired connection, the problem only occurs when I try to connect through wireless. I'm sorry if you can't fully understand what I'm saying, I just woke up, so my English is dreadful. Here is the relevant output of lspci:

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v1.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
    03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43225 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

Comment: Don't know what 'my internet' is, are you an ISP of some sort? Do you, perhaps mean the wireless network, or is it connected with a cable? Can you also post the relevant hardware specs, wireless or wired, and the output of lspci.

Comment: @mikewhatever Yeah sorry, I just woke up so my English isn't at it's best. Added the information you asked for.